# Should plagiarized posts have links when they are closed/deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation, plagiarism

I have seen [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/17443/279) answer and many others being deleted for plagiarism reason. When I personally try to dig in and find out the original text, I am usually out of luck. Can we add a link to the original post so that it is clear to other users, the answer was indeed plagiarized. This would clarify any ambiguity about plagiarized contents. What are you thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It's not always feasible, since I have seen numerous cases of plagiarism that were taken from sources that are not readily available on the Internet, or translated from foreign languages, or often just whole posts cobbled together from *multiple* third-party sources.  I've even handled flags that indicate that a post just *looks* plagiarised, but with absolutely zero actual clue as to from *where*.

The time when leaving an indication of the source is actually most valuable is when the post remains visible on the site, in order to garner the necessary delete votes.  But this can just as easily be done as a comment, or as a private flag to a moderator, or as a meta discussion with the community.

While comments can be useful guideposts for learning community norms, they are fundamentally intended to be communicated to the *author* of the post, and if the post *is* plagiarised, the *author* is well-aware of the source (better aware than the commenter, in any case).  And ultimately, if the author (or another user) *does* choose to contest the charge, proving it is far better done on meta than through ephemeral comments.